# spring integration tcp inbound cluster

Tags: spring-integration

I have tried searching for spring integration cluster for tcp inbound adapter and could not find the solution. Could some one help on clustering spring-integration tcp inbound adapter and looking for load balancing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear what your requirements are but if the client side is also Spring Integration, subscribing multiple outbound adapters (each pointing to a different server) to the same channel will cause messages to be round-robin distributed to the servers

Comment: Client side is not actually spring integration. I want to create MULTIPLE spring integration TCP servers on different nodes accepting load from a Single non-spring-integration-tcp-client for load balance. In this scenario, can we create spring integration tcp servers on different nodes accepting load (may be as cluster)

Comment: There's no notion of a "cluster"; you can deploy multiple instances but you will need either a software load balancer on the client side, or a hardware load balancer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Gary. I will check on load balancer.